# How to center div elements within a container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center an interactive element that shows my email, "container1", underneath the Contact and Paragraph text.

Right now, it seems to just sit offset left and I want it to be center while maintaining the page's responsiveness.

I can get the element to center but the page will not be responsive to mobile platforms anymore as it will still appear off center. My main goal is to have the page remain responsive.

[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVNiD.png)

```css
.container1 {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 250px auto 0;
  display: flex;
}

.container1 .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4458dc 0%, #854fee 100%), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #4458dc, #854fee);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(118, 85, 225, 1);
}

.container1 .box .icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4458dc 0%, #854fee 100%), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #4458dc, #854fee);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container1 .box .icon .fa {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container1 .box:hover .icon {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.container1 .box .details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.container1 .box:hover .details {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.container1 .box .details h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a name="Contact"></a>
<section class="contact_area section_gap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
        <div class="main_title">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
          <p>Please contact me with any questions, comments, or conerns</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container1" style="margin: auto; justify-content: center">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="display: inline-block">
      <div class="box" style="">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class='details' style="">
          <h3>myemail@gmail.com</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n27c14Lr/ - Works fine for me on this jsfiddle. Check it out.

Comment: Try removing the width and margin for `.container1`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container1 .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4458dc 0%, #854fee 100%), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #4458dc, #854fee);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(118, 85, 225, 1);
}

.container1 .box .icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4458dc 0%, #854fee 100%), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #4458dc, #854fee);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container1 .box .icon .fa {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container1 .box:hover .icon {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.container1 .box .details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.container1 .box:hover .details {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.container1 .box .details h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a name="Contact"></a>
<section class="contact_area section_gap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
        <div class="main_title">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
          <p>Please contact me with any questions, comments, or conerns</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container container1">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="display: inline-block">
      <div class="box" style="">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class='details' style="">
          <h3>myemail@gmail.com</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example:

```
.container1 { display:flex; justify-content:center;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why are you chaining classes? You can just call the class and set the style. Any inline css will override the style tags and css file. Usually if something isn't lining up the way you expect, it's being overridden somewhere else. Besides using @media to take account of element positions in mobile devices, I often center elements by using left at 50% and margin-left equal to a negative value of half the width. So for your  I'd set the css to:

```css
.detail {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 300px;  
/*(or you could have it as a percentage like 80%)*/
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
/*(or in percent example -40%)*/
text-align: center;
}
```

The positions the element center from its left side the offsets the amount that the width of the element pushes it over.